# JavaScript href onclick not working with Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, onclick, href

The below is my code. All my button functions are working perfectly, but if I click the link click the value of server should be remembered and the page should be reloaded again with the parameters view and subsys.

But the value for the server is empty when I getting reloaded.

```
my $server = $q->param('server') ;
my $unit = $q->param('unit') ;

my $bfile = __FILE__ ;
$bfile = `basename $bfile` ;
chomp $bfile ;

print "<form name=\"form1\" action =\"/cgi-bin/$bfile\" onsubmit=\"javascript:onsubmitform(doc_press)\">";

print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"server\" id=\"server\">";
print "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"unit\" id=\"unit\">";
print "\n\n<input type=submit name=view value=\"View\" onClick=\"doc_press=this.value\">";
print "<input type=submit name=save value=\"Save\" onClick=\"doc_press=this.value\">";

print $var{$a}."<a href=\"/cgi-bin/$bfile?view=5&SUBSYS=$subsys\" onClick=javascript:click_page(\"$_\")>CLICK</a>\n" ;

print <<"END_OF_SCRIPT";
<script type="text/javascript">
function onsubmitform(doc_press) {
        if (doc_press == "View"){
                document.getElementById('unit').value="$unit";
        }
        else if (doc_press == "Save") {
END_OF_SCRIPT
             var x = "$user=$val";
             document.cookie=x;
             document.getElementById('unit').value="$unit";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('HTTP_TYPE').value == "post") {
                document.form1.method='post';
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('HTTP_TYPE').value == "get") {
                document.form1.method='get';
        }
}

function click_page(server){
        document.getElementById('server').value=server;
}
</script>
END
```

Comment: `javascript:` doesn't belong into `onsomething=""` handlers. It's not a URL but JavaScript code! Also, in case you are using XHTML, it attributes have to be completely lowercase, i.e. `onclick`

Comment: This code not even compile, provide your real code. At least 6 declarations are missing in the code.

Comment: you know that you don't need all those \" in your strings right? Use qq{} and voilà: print qq{<a href="/cgi-bin/$bfile">go</a>}; Even better, use a templating system (I like the simplicity of Text::Template, but Template Toolkit is also very popular)

Comment: @daxim: i just give u the code for reference so tht u can understand my problem. my whole program is confidential. so i cant provide it here.. thank you

Comment: @mirod : thank you for that. but I am used to this.. so if i change also it will make me confusing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a link (`<a href="..."/>`), the browser will make a new GET request for the given link, regardless of any forms you might have.  This means that your form is NOT submitted; so any value in the form will be lost.  For this reason, your onclick handler as posted here is useless.

Sometimes, if you’re really linking to the same page, modern browsers are smart enough to recognize that, and fill in the values you already had.  This is only a commodity to users who get frustrated if their values are not kept, and so this doesn't work for hidden fields.

If you want clicking on the link to submit the form, you should either a) use a button, or b) change your onclick handler to submit the form and return false (so that the link isn’t followed):

```
function click_page(server){
    document.getElementById('server').value=server;
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return false;
}
```

To make this work correctly, also change the onclick declaration:

```
<a href="..." onclick="return click_page('$_')">CLICK</a>
```

Comment: hi, it worked thank you.. but i need the link to be followed because i have some more new parameters in that link that also to be considered while re-loading. is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: If your form has `method="GET"`, then the form will be posted to the URL specified in the `action` attribute, with all the form’s values appended to the URL's query string.  I see you’re already fiddling with the form’s method elsewhere; why not do it again here?

Comment: I have changed the action value. but its not getting changed. I don 't know why.It takes the link which I have defined earlier.